# Is it possible to install a C# compiler without Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, msbuild, csc

I want to build projects from the command line. Is it possible to deploy a C# compiler without installing [Visual Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio)?

Comment: hehe, I find it funny how people associate the IDE with the actual development platform and/or language.

Comment: That is the way I like to keep my build machine. Just the compiler. Of course some tools require Visual Studio, I find that really annoying in the context of build machines. You should not have to install Visual Studio in order to build anything. Some providers of 3rd party tools require Visual Studio to be installed in order to licence components and there was another reason we had to do it, can't remember what it was though.

Comment: Indeed, it is needed by the framework for some parts of .NET. If you watch the processes on your production machine and are using some functionalities requiring runtime code generation like XML Serialization, you'll notice `csc.exe` being launched by your application from time to time. Even if VS is not installed.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Sure, the framework includes a compiler, csc.exe. Look at [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20090426124057/http://www.tipsntracks.com/52/get-a-free-csharp-command-line-compiler.html) for a quick how-to. The important parts:

> You can get the command-line compiler (csc.exe) from Microsoft site
>   http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa731542.aspx.
>
> Download the redistributable package of the .NET Framework, which includes the compiler and the .NET Framework with C# 2005 syntax support.
>
> The compiler is located in the following
>   directory:
>   %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\

Also look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379563(VS.80).aspx) for a full guide and explanation.

Note that for more recent versions, you will be looking for the MSBuild standalone package rather than the framework -- see [@Vadzim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47624225/44853).

Comment: Is it possible to compile a solution not just .cs files?

Comment: Yes, that's what msbuild.exe is for.  (It can definitely handle .csproj, and I think maybe .sln too.)

Comment: MSBuild has no problems with .sln files

Comment: @200_success Thanks. I've changed the link to hit the Wayback Machine and included some of the original text.

Answer (score 47):

Of course.  Do:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-gmcs
```

Everyone else assumed Windows and MS .NET, but...

Comment: Everyone assumed, because there is only one adequate OS for desktop - Windows. Above that people asks "not installing VS", meaning he is under Windows, but don't want to install VS (because VS doesn't exist for Linux).

Answer (score 35):

Yes, if you have the [.NET SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa496123), it's there. For example,

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v[your version number]\csc.exe
```

`msbuild.exe` should be there too, and you can use that to build project (`.csproj`) files.

Comment: csc.exe is included  in the .NET Framework, what most people think of as the runtime.  You don't need the SDK to get the compiler. Let me say that again: you don't need the SDK to get the C# compiler. The VBC and CSC compilers come with the .NET Framework.

Comment: You, Sir. You nailed it. +1 for making me browse through my computer to find what I need.

Answer (score 21):

Contrary to what some of the other answerers say, you do NOT need the SDK, just the .NET Framework to get the C# compiler, `csc.exe`.

Also, consider other (free) IDEs like [MonoDevelop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MonoDevelop), [#develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/), and [Visual C# Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_C.23_Express). (You said you don't want Visual Studio, not that you don't want an IDE at all ;) )

Answer (score 14):

Latest [Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55170) doesn't include C# compiler anymore.

But it can be installed as part of standalone [MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506178/getting-msbuild-exe-without-installing-visual-studio) tool.

Go to https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/, scroll down to "Other Tools and Frameworks" and choose "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017".

After "Visual Studio Build Tools 2017" Online Installer runs, switch to "Individual components" tab and check "C# and Visual Basic Roslyn compilers". 
This would also check MSBuild dependency. All together less than a hundred of megabytes.

The compiler installs at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe`.

Comment: This is the correct solution at 2020. I'll just note that `msbuild.exe` is not in the same folder, but one up in `Bin`

Comment: Is that the latest version though?  It says version 3.9.0-6.21160.10 which is very old.  The one in C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework says version 4.8.4084.0 but that is old too and says there is a newer version.  .NET 5.0 was released, where is the csc.exe for that???

Comment: Ok, 3.9 is Roslyn based, while the 4.8 was the old C++ version.  This website explains it https://blog.lextudio.com/the-rough-history-of-the-so-many-c-compilers-f3a85500707c

Comment: One correction: "build tools" now under "Tools for Visual Studio" section and it's just stupid web-installer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is even an open source one, [IDE SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/). You can set the compiler as a command in [UltraEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraEdit) (or some other editor of preference), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need to download and install [.NET Framework SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569263.aspx).

Here's a [link](http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/02/11/hackdotnet.html) that can help you.

Comment: you don't need the sdk, but it does give you the command-line environment which makes building easier

Answer (score 1):

You only need the .NET framework. You can use [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) to edit and the CSC.exe to compile.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for a solution like this so that I could just make small console applications using C#.

The method that worked for me was mentioned by Brian, all I did was, after creating my file to simply do:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v[your version number]\csc.exe myfile.cs
```

and it will generate your .exe file that you can then use :)

Comment: Typing in the full path every time you want to recompile is not very handy. You can add this path to the PATH env variable and type in `csc.exe myfile.cs`

Comment: I agree with @PavelBastov I just wanted to show the actual path for other users who might want to create an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have Visual Studio installed with C# included. Also, assuming you want latest version.

1. Find the path to your VS installation. Call it VSPath.
2. The CSC Compiler will be at VSPath\MSBuild(MSBuild-Version)\Bin\Roslyn

Comment: What a nonsense you're saying! Author asks "deploy a C# compiler without installing Visual Studio". NO VS!

Answer (score 0):

Like some others have mentioned [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) is deployed with the .NET Framework (versions 2.0 and 3.5) so if you have either of those installed you can build your applications without needing Visual Studio installed on the machine.