# How can I run c# source code?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to install c# compiler w/o Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861384/is-it-possible-to-install-c-sharp-compiler-w-o-visual-studio)

I've just finished Global Game Jam 13 where I served as an artist. I have the files of the game but am at a loss of how to run them. It is all .cs files and folders within folders. How do I make an executable file out of it?

Comment: I believe the answers to this question can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861384/is-it-possible-to-install-c-sharp-compiler-w-o-visual-studio

Comment: Does it have a .csproj or a .csproj.user file? If you could post those we may be able to help. Or even a .sln.

Comment: @ofstream I'm not sure I understand how pasting a csproj/sln helps

Comment: No I forgot MSBuild existed. A .sln/.csproj has the locations of all the files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Load it up into Visual Studio. This should be the `.sln` file, if one doesn't exist, there would be a `.csproj` file.

You can get the free, express edition [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products) - you will need the Windows Desktop edition, most likely.

To build and launch you <kbd>F5</kbd> is the usual keyboard shortcut.

Comment: +1: although you should explain about release mode and where to look for the .exe

Comment: @Baboon - Express editions will not have a separate Debug/Release configuration. They are stripped down versions, after all.

Comment: It appears it's only once you activated "expert" settings in the express edition oO

Comment: @Oded I can tell you I have release configuration on my Express edition.

Comment: @Baboon - I was not aware of that option. Thank you for teaching me something today :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider using [MONO](http://mono-project.com/) which is a free software, multi-platform, implementation of C#.

However, in all cases, you'll need to compile your C# source code into CIL bytecode at least.

Comment: -1: you're totally missing the point.

Comment: No, he's not. He's merely suggesting another compiler.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want build it, and there is a .csproj or .sln file, you can use msbuild from the command line:

```
msbuild proj_file.csproj
msbuild solution_file.sln
```

MSBuild is located in the .Net framework install folder, which is `%WINDIR%/Microsoft .Net/Framework(64)\version\`

If there's no csproj or solution files you will have to use the C# compiler directly (csc.exe) - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2fdbz5xd.aspx).