# Running c# console app built in notepad++

Tags: c#, .net, notepad++

I am used to write code in VS 2008 < . However now I had to start using Notepad++, and I can't get to run even the HelloWorld program. I followed the steps based in this tutorial: http://www.mastercsharp.com/Article/89/writing-your-first-c-program-hello-world-net-v1-1-
I have .NET SDK 2.0 installed, but I still can't get the code running. Basically when I try to execute the file from CMD Propmpt I get a message "HelloWorld" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Is there anything else that should be installed? I have everything installed to be able to run the code, but I still can't get it to run. Any help will be apreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: That means there is no HelloWorld exe in your current dir or dirs that are on PATH

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861384/is-it-possible-to-install-c-sharp-compiler-w-o-visual-studio

Comment: Well my problem was more that the code was not running, and all the solutions I looked up didn't work. Joey gave the answer I was looking for. Anyways thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your program in Notepad++ (or any other text editor). Then on the console use

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe HelloWorld.cs
```

to compile it. Afterwards you can run the generated executable.

Comment: It seems to work, the only problem is that when I run the generated exe it exits really fast so I don't know if it runs it correct or not. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Put Console.ReadLine() at the end of your code to make it wait for the user to press Return.

Comment: I thought you're trying from the console anyway in which case the window should not disappear after your program exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run HelloWorld.cs, you need to compile it into an executable. [Use `csc` for that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/78f4aasd.aspx).

Or just install Visual Studio Express, it's free.

Answer (score -1):

You can install [CS-Script](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/694248/Sharpening-Notepadplusplus) plugin for Notepad++. The plugin allows execution of the C# code (scripts) directly from Notepad++, without the need for any infrastructure (e.g. project file). It also offers convenient launching of the C# scripts with the system CLR Debugger (e.g. VS) attached.