# Visual Studio through MSDN: Can they know it is not mine?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msdn

So, I was arguing with a great friend of mine about Visual Studio 2012 and Microsoft being able to detect which one you used. According to him if you get your hands on a direct MSDN download of Visual Studio 2012 Professional, and you end up creating an app, like a game or something, and then you submit it to the Windows App Store, they will never know which visual studio version you truly used to develop the App, or if you were the owner of it or not.

Is he right? Because I thought Visual Studio some how left a footprint behind on the .exe file letting Microsoft know about licensing information. Or should I go apologize to him for calling him a f...ing liar.

If you guys say it does leave a print, can you show some proof, or a link to read more about it? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your friend is likely correct. Why would MS bother when they make freely available all the tools you need to compile your program. You can build .Net applications without the Visual Studio IDE. See this related question

[Is it possible to install a C# compiler without Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861384/is-it-possible-to-install-c-sharp-compiler-w-o-visual-studio)