# Getting msbuild.exe without installing Visual Studio

Tags: msbuild

How do you get msbuild.exe without installing those crazy Visual Studio programs?

I need it for an npm install to finish working. I'm on Windows 7  and can't get on older version of Visual Studio 2013 Express online.

Comment: It comes with the .NET framework as far as I know. Otherwise just the Windows SDK will be needed.

Comment: @leppie As of VS 2013, [it is no longer part of the .NET Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/07/24/msbuild-is-now-part-of-visual-studio.aspx). The older versions are still included with the framework.

Comment: Related post - [How can I install the VS2017 version of msbuild on a build server without installing the IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42696948/465053)

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The latest (as of Jan 2019) stand-alone MSBuild installers can be found here: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/

Scroll down to "Tools for Visual Studio 2019" and choose "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019" (despite the name, it's for users who *don't* want the full IDE)

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42696948/1364007) question for additional information.

Comment: It took a while to find where `MSBuild.exe` was installed. By default, it is here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin`

Comment: See, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42696948/1364007) which goes into some detail about how to just install the Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools (and not the IDE too).

Comment: The tool is now listed under `Tools for Visual Studio 2017` instead of the `Other Tools and Framework` section.

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin - is the location today

Comment: In Visual Studio 2022, the tool is installed in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin`

Answer (score 22):

It used to be installed with the .NET framework.  MsBuild v12.0 (2013) is now bundled as a stand-alone utility and has it's own installer.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=40760

To reference the location of MsBuild.exe from within an MsBuild script, use the default $(MsBuildToolsPath) property.

Comment: but this version is obsolete (now). how do I get v15?

Comment: @Rigel I don't know if you specifically want VS2015's build tools, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42696948/1364007) goes into some detail about getting the 2017 tools.

Answer (score 4):

You can also get the MSBuild executable as a Nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build.Runtime/.

Answer (score 0):

Download MSBuild with the link from @Nicodemeus [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25510499/42418) was OK, yet the installation was broken until I've added these keys into a register:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\12.0]
"VCTargetsPath11"="$([MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('$(VCTargetsPath11)','$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\\Microsoft.Cpp\\v4.0\\V110\\'))"
"VCTargetsPath"="$([MSBuild]::ValueOrDefault('$(VCTargetsPath)','$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\\Microsoft.Cpp\\v4.0\\V110\\'))"
```