# How can I install the VS2017 version of msbuild on a build server without installing the IDE?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, build-tools, build-server

Historically, this has been done with the [Microsoft Build Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159). But it seems that [the Build Tools may not be available for versions after 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/introducing-the-visual-studio-build-tools/). The replacement appears to be the Visual Studio build tools, which doesn't seem to have a real homepage yet.

I downloaded the [VS2017 Professional installer](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/), and went to the **Individual Components** tab. Right away, the summary is telling me that the Visual Studio core editor is there, taking up 753MB. I don't want the editor. Just msbuild. There is no way to unselect the editor.

Is there a way I can install the latest version of msbuild without also installing the Visual Studio IDE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TFS 2015 build task for VS 2017](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694100/tfs-2015-build-task-for-vs-2017)

Comment: That question is phrased with a bad title that hides the real question. It didn't come up in a search. Your answer is a link and run, which is bad. The number of views is low, and it's "newer" than this one in a way that won't matter a day from now, let alone next year. So sure, it's a "duplicate" in the worst possible sense.

Comment: I disagree with the suggestion of a duplicate.  I found this SO q&a as top result for my search for: "how to install msbuild 2017 on build server" - and the top answer addresses my need precisely.  Having read the suggested duplicate, that answer is a full level more detailed about issues moving from one version to another - that SO post *does not* answer the question I searched for.

Comment: Related post - [Getting msbuild.exe without installing Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25506178/465053)

Answer (score 332, accepted):

The Visual Studio Build tools are a different download than the IDE. They appear to be a pretty small subset, and they're called **Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019** ([download](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019)).

You can use the GUI to do the installation, or you can script the installation of msbuild:

```
vs_buildtools.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools --quiet
```

**Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools** is a "wrapper" ID for [the three subcomponents you need](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools):

- Microsoft.Component.MSBuild
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreBuildTools
- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler

You can find documentation about the other available CLI switches [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio).

The build tools installation is *much* quicker than the full IDE. In my test, it took 5-10 seconds. With `--quiet` there is no progress indicator other than a brief cursor change. If the installation was successful, you should be able to see the build tools in `%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin`.

If you don't see them there, try running without `--quiet` to see any error messages that may occur during installation.

Comment: The abovementioned directory is definitely not created. I've removed the `--quiet` flag with identical result, except for a modal window popping up for a bit before disappearing.

Comment: I would have a look at the Windows Event Viewer to see if there are any log messages about why the installation failed. And then correct those or ask a new question that's specific to your problem.

Comment: Also, dont use `--quiet` mode if you're building ASP.net web applications on your build server - as you will want to select "Web development build tools" during the install wizard so that the correct MSBuild targets are installed.

Comment: Looks like instead of build tools link refers to vs community. Here is buildtools link: https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe

Comment: @rianjs, I installed this on my build server(Bamboo), however when solution gets built, it throws error `MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web\Sd‌​k\Sdk.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.` unable to understand why it still doesn't find this path.

Comment: I installed this and package restore via NuGet does not seem to work. Any one else experience this?

Comment: Is there an offline version of this ? My build server has no internet access.

Comment: @IamCP : to copy VS2017 installation environment into a local machine :


    cd G:\ISO;
    .\vs_Professional.exe --layout G:\ISO\VS2017ProOffline --lang en-US ;
    .\vs_BuildTools.exe --layout G:\ISO\VS2017BuildToolsOffline --lang en-US ;

Then you can copy to your offline target.

Comment: unfortunately at the moment MSBuild from the suggested package is affected by [this issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/25594/visual-studio-build-tools-2017-is-missing-msbuild.html), which manifests itself with `The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found`. Please upvote the issue, so that M$ finally fixes it.

Comment: --quiet flag failed for me.  The Installer folder was there but no other folders where the msbuild should have been.  I was able to confirm by digging in the log, which is in c:\users\[username]\appdata\local\temp.  The error was saying that it could not find the component specified Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools.  It did seem to work ok in --passive mode though.  weird.

Comment: I'd guess this _isn't_ "much quicker than the full IDE." If you had `vs_buildtools` available, you already had the dotnet framework installed. On a server without a current dotnet, it just spent 20 minutes installing the framework, and is currently taking its time with dotnet core. If you'd installed the full Visual Studio, on a new system, it would have had to do all that, too. Still, I got what I needed from the answer :-)

Comment: I did not use quiet and it came up with the gui and an option which was 71MB and previously unavailable.   But after that had been displayed I had to press Install to continue.  Seemed to work ok. Thanks.

Comment: I need to install it on a build server which does not have internet connection. Is there anyway to download it for offline installation?

Comment: I love how someone edited the answer to give a link to the Visual Studio 2019 build tools. Let's make this issue even more confusing.

Comment: I wanted a GUI-less terminal only solution, but `--quiet` mode is not very good: it returns very quickly, and the installation continues in background process `vs_installerservice.exe` and you have no way to know the progress (1% ? 100%? 50%? failed?). Here there is no verbosity at all :(

Answer (score 4):

For MsBuild 17, which is part of VS2022, you need to download the Build tools for VS2022 here (which is actually just the installer):

https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_BuildTools.exe

(This link can be found by going to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads and scrolling all the way down to "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2022".)

Once downloaded you can install by typing:

```
vs_buildtools.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools --quiet --wait
```

Depending on your needs you might also need to specify `--includeRecommended` and possibly `--includeOptional`.

If you are doing web development you probably also want to add `--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools`.

Input parameters and return codes are available here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022