# How to install MSBuild 15.3 without Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Is there a way to install version 15.3 of MSBuild on the build server without installing Visual Studio 2017?

I tried to install 'Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017' from https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/ per https://stackoverflow.com/a/42697374/ however I ended up with version 15.1:

```
msbuild /version
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.1012.6693
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

15.1.1012.6693
```

We need version 15.3 to build Azure Functions project.

Comment: Since Visual Studio 2017 15.3 is previews version, and not officially released. You could not download the MSBuild 15.3 without VS IDE until the Visual Studio is officially released. Installing VS 2017 on build server can not be accepted for you?

Comment: @Leo-MSFT Yeah, I prefer not to install full-blown Visual Studio on the build server.

Comment: MSBuild 15.7 is now available from the link in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install the VS2017 version of msbuild on a build server without installing the IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696948/how-can-i-install-the-vs2017-version-of-msbuild-on-a-build-server-without-instal)

Comment: @WaiHaLee: if i click on https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/ link & then go to Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019 and click download, it tries to download Visual Studio 2017 community edition.

Comment: @SharpCoder that's... weird. I clicked on the link and was taken [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=16) which then started downloading the online installer for the build tools.

Comment: @WaiHaLee: I got confused with the message that appears at the top. it says thank you for downloading visual studio. But I want a offline installer. Online installer will not work for me.

Comment: @SharpCoder - see [Create an offline installation of Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 6):

at the time of writing MSBuild 15.3 hasn't been released outside of preview versions of Visual Studio or the .NET Core CLI 2.0.0 previews.

When it is released, it will be part of VS 2017 15.3 (+ Build Tools), .NET Core CLI 2.0.0 and Mono 5.2

Comment: Is it available now. Still not able to down Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 or Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 6):

Answer of this question may help you

[How can I install the VS2017 version of msbuild on a build server without installing the IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42697374/1442180)

> The Visual Studio Build tools are a different download than the IDE. They appear to be a pretty small subset, and they're called Build
>   Tools for Visual Studio 2017 ([Download](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017))
>
> You can use the GUI to do the installation, or you can script the
>   installation of msbuild:
>
> `vs_buildtools.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools --quiet`

Answer (score 4):

go to the microsoft website and download vs_buildtools (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)
after the download access the folder through the CMD prompt and start the installation through the commands below:

> vs_buildtools__1882505178.1548260078.exe --layout c:\VS_BuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --lang en-US --includingOptional

- "vs_buildtools__1882505178.1548260078.exe" should be replaced with the version you downloaded to the site.
- "c:\VS_BuildTools" path where the installer should be.

Answer (score 3):

You can always build from source: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/releases