# WinForms App in .Net Framework 4.8 can't build from command line

Tags: c#, .net

I have written a winforms app in visual studio 2019 targeting .Net Framework 4.8. It compiles and runs when using Visual Studio. Happy days.

I then setup Jenkins to build my solution on a Windows Agent. This is where the problems start.

Initially I was trying to compile using the command.

```
dotnet build happy.sln
```

After looking at the csproj files I notice they are not Sdk format and everything I've read says that the command "dotnet build" only works on projects of Sdk format.

So after all the waffling. I'm looking for advice.
What do I need to install on my Jenkins Windows Agent so I can call **MSBuild** on the command line. Also where would MSBuild be installed.
I'm not going to install Visual Studio 2019 on the build agent.

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install MSBuild 15.3 without Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003516/how-to-install-msbuild-15-3-without-visual-studio)

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003516/how-to-install-msbuild-15-3-without-visual-studio

Comment: I will have a go at installing the Visual Studio build tools and report back.