# MSBuild of VS2017 cannot compile .NET Standard 2.0 project

Tags: msbuild, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I have a csproj which targets .NET framework 4.6.1  and .NET Standard 2.0.

It can be compiled in my local machine with Visual Studio 2017 (v15.3.2)

Now I am setting up our building server(Jenkins) to include this project. Our building server works fine for other .NET framework 4.6.1 projects.

First, I copied the toolchain from my local machine (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\`) to the building server.

Then I configured Jenkins to use the MSBuild v15.3.409.57025, which was copied from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`

But it results in the following error on compilation

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(126,5):
>   error : The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Standard
>   2.0.  Either target .NET Standard 1.6 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Standard 2.0.

The file `Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets` was also copied from my local machine `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets`. I checked its content in my local machine and saw a line below.

`<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">`

The `ToolsVersion` is still `14.0` in my VS2017 directory?

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt coping the VS installation folder is enough here - after all VS is not xcopy-deployable. If you can't, or don't want to, install VS on the build server, consider [installing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42697374/21567) the Build Tools (for 2017) only.

Comment: @Christian.K, copying MSBuild always works from my experience. I will try to install VS2017 on building server but I don't think that is the cause

Comment: The build tools now (15.3) have the necessary SDK resolver but lack the integrated NuGet support required for .NET Core/Standard projects, so a "full" version is still needed (until probably 15.4).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You also need to install the .NET Core 2.0.0 SDK since the VS installation only includes the `1.1.0` tasks and targets and looks for other installed versions that are compatible with the current msbuild version (or there is a global.json file in the project that pins a different version).

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: VS needs to be restarted after the installation of the SDK for everything to be correctly recognized.