# MSBuild 15 missing after installation

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, visual-studio-2017

I have recently upgraded to VS2017 and building with TeamCity. I have a new project that I need to build using TeamCity. 
I tried to install MS Build on the CI server from the following link https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/ it said that it has successfully installed it. Restarted the CI server trying to build the project and still cannot find the new Build tools.

I checked under C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0\ but I dont see the MSBuild.exe

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolve this issue? If not, please let me know, I will keep follow it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> MSBuild 15 missing after installation

If you want use MSBuild without install Visual Studio, you should download and install `vs_BuildTools.exe` from below link:

https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15#

After installation complete, you will find the MSBuild.exe under the path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin
```

[image]

For more detail information, you can refer to: [How can I install the VS2017 version of msbuild on a build server without installing the IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696948/how-can-i-install-the-vs2017-version-of-msbuild-on-a-build-server-without-instal)

Answer (score 5):

MSBuild is now local to Visual Studio 2017
 and multiple versions can be installed side-by-side (e.g. build tools, previews, community + enterprise, etc.)

So a path to `msbuild.exe` could look like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin
```

Comment: But I dont want to install Visual Studio on the Continuous Integration server.

Comment: You can also install the build tools. But their path will look similar (afaik `BuildTools` instead of `Enterprise`)

Comment: No they are not installed on same path. VS 2017 installs MSBuild on C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\, whereas standalone MSBUilTools are installed on C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0.
Problem I am facing is TeamCity is looking VS path not the one where is is actually installed.

Comment: @WSK maybe you could go with a symlink (https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)