# Enable NuGet package manager in VS Installer through command line. (as part of automated script)

Tags: .net, jenkins, command-line, nuget, nuget-package

I want to enable NuGet package manager through the command line but I am not sure how to do it.

We have a Jenkins pipeline that installs MSBuild15 BuildTools (using choco commands) and I need to enable NuGet package manager as part of the automated script.

If I enable it directly on the server/agent then the compilation of the solution is successful but I need to automate this step.

I have attached an image of what it looks like through vs_installer ->
[Image of VS Installer, what i need to enable through command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6MQx.png)

Comment: Are you sure this is "enabling" NuGet and not simply adding nuget.exe to a directory that's covered by your PATH?

You can find the NuGet executables (not installers, full executables) here: https://www.nuget.org/downloads 

Try dropping one of these into a folder that's covered by your PATH environment variable.

Comment: @JoeCullinan when we don't enable NuGet a "Clean" of the solution fails with the following error;

_CoreClean:
Creating directory "obj\Release\".
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1657,5): error MSB4036: The "GetReferenceNearestTargetFrameworkTask" task was not found._

According to this document the answer is to enable "NuGet package manager"
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47797510/the-getreferencenearesttargetframeworktask-task-was-not-found)

after I done this the clean & build worked.

Comment: @JoeCullinan I want to enable this feature through the command line automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work in Powershell:

> Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\vs_installer.exe" -ArgumentList 'modify --installPath
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
>   --quiet --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet.BuildTools --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.TargetingPack --norestart --force' -Wait
>   -PassThru

Found here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/137779/the-getreferencenearesttargetframeworktask-task-wa.html#reply-160786

Comment: Thanks I have tested in a PowerShell module and it works a treat, cheers!

Comment: Alternate installer path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\installer\vs_installer.exe`