# how to compile asp.net mvc 5 in C# 7 without vs

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild

I have use C# 7 syntax in our asp.net mvc 5 project. Now I want to deploy it to my server. I have known how to use VS IDE to compile it. But I need use prompt tools(msbuild?) to compile our project. I find the way to use msbuild, but it doesn't support C#7 syntax. I don't want to drop my C#7 syntax code. I plan to clone a code copy from git, then use Nuget to restore the necessary librarys, then start compile the whole projcect. Do you have any better ideas on my plan or help me to solve the msbuild doesn't recognize C# 7 syntax? One more, I don't want to install a VS IDE on my deployment server. Just want install .net framework runtime only.

Comment: If it don't compile that only mean you're not using the correct version of msbuild. Which version of msbuild you  use?

Comment: You _are_ using msbuild version 15, right? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696948/how-can-i-install-the-vs2017-version-of-msbuild-on-a-build-server-without-instal)

Comment: thanks john,that's good answer!