# How to build the MSBuild.exe after cloning the git

Tags: windows, git, msbuild

I am trying to get MSBuild.exe without installing any Microsoft Visual Studio in Windows 10. I found it possible to get the git of MSBuild.exe from here:

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild.git
```

But I don't know how to build the MSBuild.exe once cloned the branch. The instructions in the repository are to build it with Visual Studio 2017. But I read it is possible to get MSBuild.exe without installing any Visual Studio.

I am really new at this, so maybe similar questions have been asked about this topic but I wasn't able to find them. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What platform are you on? The README has build instructions for Visual Studio and OSX.

Comment: @evolutionxbox The problem is I can not install Visual Studio. I don't have permissions. So I was trying to find other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to build MsBuild yourself which is only part of the tools you need.

> But I read it is possible to get MSBuild.exe without installing any Visual Studio.

Yes, you should install "Microsoft Build Tools".

Use your preferred search engine to find it or look at:

[How can I install the VS2017 version of msbuild on a build server without installing the IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696948/how-can-i-install-the-vs2017-version-of-msbuild-on-a-build-server-without-instal)