# Nuget Restore in a Docker Container

Tags: visual-studio, docker, msbuild

I am trying run `nuget restore mySolution.sln` in a docker container.

For the most part it seems to work just fine.  The packages seem to restore fine, but before they do, it shows this error:

```
C:\src\myProject\mySolution.csproj(317,11): 
error MSB4226: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. 

Also, tried to find "WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" in the fallback search path(s) for $(VSToolsPath) 
      - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0" . 

These search paths are defined in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\bin\msbuild.exe.Config". Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.
```

From what I read, this means I need the nuget package `MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets`.  I did a nuget install of that, but the error does not go away.  (It just drops it where ever I run it.  I tried putting it with my solution and in the packages folder.  Neither had any effect.)

**How can I fix this error using command line tools?** (No GUI because this is a docker container).

Comment: I don't think it's a package that you are missing. 
You are missing the SDK/targets that are required to build that web project.
You are missing the web workload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume what you're trying to build is a web-application, but you haven't installed corresponding workloads in your build tools package.And that's the cause of this issue. (Agree with **imps**)

Open the **Visual Studio Installer** in `Start menu` and you can modify the workloads of your msbuild package:

[image]

I only use the msbuild build tools package to build C++ desktop projects in server, so I only install the `Visual C++ build tools workload`. For you, you have to install the `build tools for Web applications` so that you can get the necessary files to build web-applications.

**Update:**

```
error: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found.
```

After I install the `Web development build tools`, I now get the newly created **WebApplications** folder in path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am doing this in a Docker Container.  I have no access to GUI tools...

Comment: @Vaccano Just like VS, msbuild package supports installing by command-line. See [install options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#install-options) and the [ID:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2019#web-development-build-tools) you need.

Comment: @Vaccano My installer.exe is `vs_buildtools_xxx.xxx.exe`, so i use a command like: `vs_buildtools__1458634494.1562658743.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools --quiet`.   `--quiet` means installation without UI, and I think you need to run the cmd as admin.

Comment: Similar issue see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42697374/10910450). And [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container?view=vs-2019#create-and-build-the-dockerfile) may make some help for you:)