# gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

[image]I used the command `truffle unbox react` to build a dapp. It is just the initial step of my dapp development. However, it sucks. It continually pops up

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
```

this error. I've already google this error. Therefore, I set my python default version at 2.7 and install visual studio 2015 and visual studio 2017. Also I've reinstall node-gyp and npm to make sure if it is the latest version. And also, `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` I've tried whatever I can google. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Oh, I encoutered this one when fiddling with web3, 
if the npm windows-build-tools failed, try to open your VS2017, create a c++ console app build it and run it. Then restart your terminal and reinstall.

Also I set the npm config
npm config set msvs_version 2017 --global

Comment: @keys! Thanks for replying me. I've tried your solution, however it still not working. Did I misunderstand something? Can ```npm config``` be command individually?

Comment: I've command ```npm config set msvs_version 2017 --global```, it ran smoothly. If I try ```npm config```, it gives me this error ```npm ERR! Usage:```

Comment: your right you just need to run npm config set msvs_version 2017 --global

Comment: just to make sure? are you running the cmd as administrator?

Comment: @keys! Yes, I am. I am running under windows environment.

Comment: hmmm that's weird, maybe node-gyp is corrupted or something. dumb advice, have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: @keys! Yes, I've tried it several times. This error makes me wonder if I have to build this dapp under Linux environment. Does this move make my dapp build smoother?

Comment: Build Tools for VS2017 is different from VS2017 IDE. The error message indicates you're using build Tools, please make sure you've met all requirements according to this [document](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows).

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Really appreciate for replying me. I've install both Build Tools for VS2017 and also VS2017 community. What do you mean? Please be more specific.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Maybe I failed to install C++ workload. I don't know where the package is. How can I install it? Please help.

Comment: You can follow [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57492119/10910450) to check if you've installed C++ workload, but if this issue occurs though you've configured the build tools well, I think this issue results from node.js version or what, which I'm not familiar with :(

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Is ```Desktop Development with C++``` the C++ workload package that you have mention above?

Comment: Now, I've installed Visual c++ Build tools. However, it still pops up the same error. What can I do to solve this error? I feel really hopeless right now. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

I also had this problem, And finally I didn't realize what was going on.

but

my problem was solved that way

> I uninstall node 12.14.1 and install 10.18.1 It's working now.

Comment: I faced the same problem on Node 13 on Windows 10. Uninstalled Node 13 and installed 11.6 and now it works for me too, thanks

Comment: I can't see how this could be a valid solution when you need to run also modules that require more recent version of npm

Comment: @ِِDecagrog I guess the packages we use are in accordance with the version of node that was released at the time And often not all packages are updated at node speed