# (C++17; Boost) CMake unable to find the requested Boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost, c++17

I am new to C++ and want to include the boost library (specifically the filesystem part which needs to be built) in my project. I tried many solutions from other stackoverflow users but they didn't help me at all. I am using CLion with CMake.
The main.cpp is calling the other .cpp files inside the *modules/* folder.

The file structure:

```
ProjectName
    >boost
        >lots of folders and .hpp files
    >cmake-build-debug
    >modules
        encryption.cpp
        encryption.h
        output.cpp
        output.h
    CMakeLists.txt
    main.cpp
```

The boost folder doesn't contain the entirety of boost when you download and extract it. I dragged the boost folder inside of *boost_1_72_0* in my project (just so you know that there's no *libs* folder, etc. inside)

The CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(ProjectName)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc")

set(SOURCE_FILES
        main.cpp
        modules/encryption.cpp modules/encryption.h modules/output.cpp modules/output.h
        )

set(Boost_ARCHITECTURE -x64)
set(BOOST_ROOT boost/)
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS boost/filesystem)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

add_executable(ProjectName ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(ProjectName ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

output.cpp

```
// some includes //
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED

#include "../boost/filesystem.hpp"

// some code //
```

The Error message:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2019.1.4/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2147 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
  directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
  Boost's headers.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/username/Desktop/C++/ProjectName/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Makefile:235: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
```

I know that it's basically telling me what I have to do but I don't know what's exactly meant by the "root directory" of boost, by the directory "containing Boost's headers" and how to put everything together.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> I dragged the boost folder inside of boost_1_72_0 in my project

Looks like you just copied boost source into your project dir. 
You have to [compile](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#simplified-build-from-source) boost since you need filesystem. Or you can get boost from:

- [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) - it's the easiest way for you. I am highly recommended this way.
- [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.72.0/).
- [Conan](https://conan.io/)

> I don't know what's exactly meant by the "root directory"...

Since you are using `boost` by calling `find_package(Boost)` - CMake uses [FindBoost](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) module. It will try to find your boost installation inside system `PATH` variable or in some other "standard" places. Your boost "installation" is not common, so you have to specify where boost is with BOOST_ROOT variable. `set(BOOST_ROOT boost/)` is incorrect way to do this. You have to specify absolute path like `set(BOOST_ROOT "C:/lib/boost/boost17.2")`
or relative to current CMakeList.txt - `set(BOOST_ROOT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/boost}`.

With right installed boost all you have to do is:

```
    find_package(Boost REQUIRED [COMPONENTS <libs>...])
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
    target_include_directories(main PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Comment: I added your solution to my CMakeLists.txt file but I still have to compile boost. For some reason vcpkg won't work (I'm getting and MSBuild with C++ support error). When compiling boost manually with *bootstrap.bat* I get an error in the logfile: *Unknown toolset: vcunk*.

Comment: @Frenggie vcpkg required MSVC compiler. Do you have Visual Studio with c++ tools or standalone VS build tools installed?

Comment: I have Visual Studio but without C++ tools. I am using CLion with mingw and cmake. Is there any way to build boost without any VS build tools?

Comment: I am installing 12 GB of Build Tools right now just to be sure I got anything I need. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696948/how-can-i-install-the-vs2017-version-of-msbuild-on-a-build-server-without-instal) thread with the command from the top answer. I hope this will be it.

Comment: @Frenggie Yes, you can build boost with MinGW. Also you can create custom MinGW [triplet](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/users/triplets.md) for vcpkg. But I suggest you stick with MSVC. You can add [MSVC compiler to CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/quick-tutorial-on-configuring-clion-on-windows.html#MSVC).

Comment: I've installed VC Build libraries. But when I wanted to do the user wide integration of vcpkg my windows defender gave me a warning for Trojan:Virus\FueryC!cl. It's probably bs but I am kinda paranoid. Could there be a problem with vcpkg or my C++ installation?

Comment: @Frenggie VCPKG is a Microsoft project. Warning about Trojan sound… weird for me and I never ever had such “problem” before on all my Windows (7/8/10) machines with Defender ON. Consider creating an issue on VCPKG GitHub page and check your PC with some free AV utilities like [CureIT](https://free.drweb.com/download+cureit+free/?lng=en) or [KAV Removal Tool](https://www.kaspersky.com/downloads/thank-you/free-virus-removal-tool)

Comment: I already ran 4 scans through the night (Defender Fast Scan, Defender Full Scan, Malwarebytes full scan, Malwarebytes scan of vcpkg files) and I uploaded vkpkg to Virustotal in case the project got compromised (very unlikely but possible I guess). No even one virus alert from those scans. The Defender message pointed directly on vcpkg.exe in the github files. Oh and I did an defender offline scan.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you don't need to set `Boost_ARCHITECTURE` and `Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS` CMake does it for you.

When you use `find_package` with `REQUIRED` option you don't need to check whether the library found or not since CMake raises an error when a library isn't found.

`BOOST_ROOT` is a directory when boost installed or unpacked.
`BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` is a directory with boost headers (usually it's `BOOST_ROOT/boost`). So try to set the full path to your `boost_1_72_0` directory to `BOOST_ROOT` CMake variable.

Also, I had a problem with `COMPONENTS` option. Try to remove it if errors remain.