# I'm trying to compile the code into a dll in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, dll

```
PS E:\ssss> dotnet build -c Release
MSBuild version 17.3.2+561848881 for .NET
Definition of projects for recovery...
```

There is no work. There are no packages in any of these projects that can be restored.

I receive a build error:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.420\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1220,5): error MSB36
44: No reference assemblies were found for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1. To fix this problem,
install the developer package (SDK or targeting package) for this version of the platform or
update the application. Developer packages for the platform .The NET Framework can be downloaded on the following pages
e https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks . 
    Errors: 1
```

When entering the `dotnet build -c Release` command, it returns an error.

I tried to install it, `.NetFramework,Version=v4.7.1`.

Does not install says there are later versions how to fix this problem?

Comment: you need to istall the sdk of Framework 4.71, as i needed yosterday 4.72 i donwload it from M$ and couldn't install it, so i starte the visual studio installer and changed the VS 2022 to also use 4.72. VS code has not that ability, so you could install VS 2022 and compile the dll there, so you can install every Framework you like and neeed

Comment: According to [dotnet build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build): _This article applies to: ✔️ .NET Core 3.1 SDK and later versions_.  See [.NET versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-and-net-core) and [.NETFramework versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework) - you'll notice that they are two separate products. For _.NETFramework_ use [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2022)

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Getting msbuild.exe without installing Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506178/getting-msbuild-exe-without-installing-visual-studio)

Comment: @user246821, the .NET (Core) SDK can target .NET Framework versions too, assuming the required _Developer Pack_ is installed manually, as instructed in the error message; download from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks

Comment: @mklement0: While _dotnet build_ does appear to call _MSBuild_, the documentation doesn't state that _.NETFramework_ is supported by _dotnet build_. Do you have any references to support what you've stated? If so, please share them.

Comment: @user246821, it is unfortunate that the documentation doesn't state that. In practice, it works - though I'm unclear on some aspects. Please see my answer, and if you have additional information, please provide feedback there.

Answer (score 0):

While the documentation for the **[.NET (Core) SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/sdk)**'s CLI, [`dotnet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet) currently suggests otherwise, **it *is* possible to target specific versions of the *legacy .NET Framework*, such as 4.7.1**, with `msbuild.exe` in effect<sup>[1]</sup> being used behind the scenes.

Because the .NET SDK is what underlies building C# projects in *Visual Studio Code*, you can therefore also develop such projects in the latter.

**Note**:

- Given the apparent lack of documentation for using the .NET SDK to target the legacy .NET Framework, it isn't clear whether doing so is officially supported; however, the fact that the underlying `msbuild.exe` and `nuget.exe` functionality seems capable of targeting  both .NET editions (as implied by the error message you saw) is encouraging.

However, **some additional steps** are required:

- You need to install a *Developer Pack* for the desired legacy .NET Framework version - see https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks (while these packs are designed for *Visual Studio*, they also work with the .NET SDK).

  - NOTE: *I'm unclear on whether this is still needed with recent .NET SDK versions*, as on my machine with v8 of the .NET SDK installed it also works *without* this installation - do let us know if you have more information.
  - `donet --info` will *not* reflect which such Developer Packs, if any, are installed.
- When initializing *new* projects with `dotnet new ...`, you can *not* directly target legacy .NET Frameworks and must manually edit the `.csproj` file afterwards (the `-f` (`--framework`) option for [`dotnet new`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new) does *not* accept *.NET Framework* [TFMs (target framework monikers)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks) such as `net471`) as of .NET SDK 8.

  - E.g., replace `<TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>` with `<TargetFramework>net471</TargetFramework>` to target .NET Framework 4.7.1, for instance.
  - Additionally given that .NET Framework-targeted applications are limited to C# v7.3, you must remove `<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>` and `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` from the `*.csproj`
  - Also, because [*top-level statements*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates) aren't available in C# v7.3 either (they require v10), you must replace the `Program.cs` content with the old-style approach of defining a CLI entry point (a `Program` class with a static `Main()` method, as shown below).
  - The sample code below bypasses these steps by creating the sample project's files from scratch.

---

##### The following *self-contained sample code* automates the above:

- It create a `.\sample` console-application project in the current directory,  as follows:

  - It downloads and installs the Developer Pack for .NET Framework 4.7.1, using `winget.exe`
  - It initializes the project first with the latest .NET SDK, and then replaces the `sample.csproj` and `Program.cs` files in order to target .NET Framework 4.7.1.
- **Prerequisites**:

  - The .NET (Core) SDK is assumed to already be installed - see https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download
  - You can install v8 (targeting .NET 8) with the following command (unless run from an elevated session, a UAC prompt will be presented):

    ```bash
     winget install Microsoft.DotNet.SDK.8
    ```
  - The code must be run *with elevation* (as administrator), to ensure *automated* installation of the Developer Pack.
- **Caveats**:

  - As noted, with .NET SDK 8 installed, I didn't actually have to install the Developer Pack for .NET Framework 4.7.1 - but I'm unsure on what that depends on.
  - The `*.csproj` created below is created for the .NET SDK (despite targeting .NET Framework) - I don't know what the behavior with preexisting `*.csproj` files created by *Visual Studio* is.
  - Even though all indications during the *build* are that it is indeed 4.7.1 that is targeted, *at runtime* it seems to be *v4.8.1* that is actually used; that is, the last two output lines when running the code may be (the last line is the file path of the CLR assembly):

    ```bash
    Hello from .NET Framework 4.8.9181.0
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll
    ```

    - I'm unclear what that depends on - the roll-forward behavior and configuration described in [Control roll-forward behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#control-roll-forward-behavior) seemingly apply to *NET (Core)* projects only.

```bash
#requires -RunAsAdministrator

# The .NET SDK is assumed to be already installed.
if (-not (Get-Command -ErrorAction Ignore dotnet)) {
  Write-Warning @"
Please install the .NET SDK first - go to https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download or 
run the following from an ELEVATED session, e.g. for .NET SDK 8:

   winget install Microsoft.DotNet.SDK.8

Then open a PowerShell new session via the taskbar / Start Menu and try again.
"@
  exit 2
}

Write-Verbose -Verbose "Installing the Developer Pack for .NET Framework 4.7.1..."
# Download the Developer Pack for .NET Framework 4.7.1
# and install it in an automated fashion.
# winget install Microsoft.DotNet.Framework.DeveloperPack_4 --version 4.7.1 --force --silent
if ($LASTEXITCODE) { throw "Installation failed with exit code $LASTEXITCODE."}

Write-Verbose -Verbose "Creating sample console-app project ./sample..."

$projectDir = New-Item -ErrorAction Stop -Force -Type Directory ./sample
if ((Get-Item -Force $projectDir/*).Count) { throw "Project directory ./sample already exists and is non-empty. Please either remove the old directory or clear its contents, then try again."}

# *.csproj file - target .NET Framework 4.7.1
@'
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net471</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
'@ | Set-Content ./sample/sample.csproj

# Program.cs file - report the runtime framework description and assembly location.
@'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from " + RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription);
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
    }
}
'@ | Set-Content ./sample/Program.cs

Write-Verbose -Verbose "Building the sample project..."
dotnet build ./sample
if ($LASTEXITCODE) { throw "Build failed."}

Write-Verbose -Verbose "Invoking .\sample\bin\Debug\net471\sample.exe..."
.\sample\bin\Debug\net471\sample.exe
```

---

<sup>[1] While the `msbuild.exe` and `nuget.exe` *executables* don't ship with the .NET SDK, their *functionality* is built into the `dotnet` subcommands of the latter.</sup>