# Programmatically call C# Compiler to Compile C# code

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction

I have designed my very own language that I, in the end, translate to C# code. Now I want to compile this C# code using the C# compiler through my Windows Forms Application.

Where is the actual compiler file located and how do I compile my code (currently placed in a string)??

Comment: See -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553143/compiling-executing-a-c-sharp-source-file-in-command-prompt

Comment: @DarkXphenomenon: What is the point of that? You did not read the question correctly.

Comment: He wants to compile C#. CSC is a way to do that, from the command line, and hence can be invoked from within another C# program as well.

Comment: @leppi the link is perfectly relevant to this question. Flagged your comment as rude/offensive.

Comment: @MattDavey et al. Is the command prompt programmatic? No...

Comment: @leppie is right .. I need to compile the program from my C# Application not via the Command line manually..!!

Comment: @tGilani: Perhaps the others can't read :)

Comment: @tGilani nobody said anything about manually typing commands into a command prompt window!

Comment: @MattDavey I have to concur with leppie. `csc` is not the ideal way to do that. Fortunately, the compiler is fully available via `CSharpCodeProvider`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the `CSharpCodeProvider`. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655, or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) have examples.

Answer (score 3):

You can use C# CodeDom for this purpose. This link may help you

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3445/Runtime-Compilation-A-NET-eval-statement

Answer (score 0):

```
c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\
```

contains the C# compiler `csc.exe`.

So, you could do something like the following:

```
const string outputfile = "abc.exe";
const string inputFile = "xyz.cs"

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "c:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\Framework\v3.5\\csc.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/out:" + outputFile + " " + inputFile;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: **(comments removed)** I've removed some unhelpful comments; basically, some people have observed that it may not be necessary or appropriate to shell to `csc` to achieve this. It is a *valid* answer (assuming the paths are correct for the machine, etc), but it has been argued that there may be more direct ways to achieve this. `</summary-of-comments>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at the following 2 sites:

1 - Command-line Building With csc.exe

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx

and

2 -  Determining Which Version of the .NET Framework Is Installed

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y549e41e.aspx

You will need to identify which version of the .NET Framework compiler you will use, from the second link you can see:

"You can install and run multiple versions of the .NET Framework on a computer. You can install the versions in any order. To see which versions are installed, view the %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework directory. (You should also view the Framework64 directory on a 64-bit computer, which can have 32 or 64-bit versions installed.) Each version of the .NET Framework has a directory, and the first two digits of the directory name identify the .NET Framework version; for example: v1.1.4322 for the .NET Framework 1.1, v2.0.50727 for the .NET Framework 2.0, v3.5 for the .NET Framework 3.5, and so on."

Comment: I know that (CodeDom), but part of the question was "where the csc.exe is located"...

Answer (score 0):

just use nemerle compiler as service with csharp syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using [Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50) instead?

The [csc.exe compiler is part of the .Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx):

> The csc.exe executable is usually located in the
>   Microsoft.NET\Framework\ folder under the system directory.
>   Its location may vary depending on the exact configuration on any
>   individual computer. Multiple versions of this executable will be
>   present on the computer if more than one version of the .NET Framework
>   is installed on the computer. For more information about such
>   installations, see [Determining Which Version of the .NET Framework Is
>   Installed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y549e41e.aspx).

Comment: Why suggest `Reflection.Emit`?

Comment: -1 there is no reason to scell the csc.exe since codedom does exactly what asked.

Comment: While it is *valid* (I use Emit a lot), it is a bit like answering "how do I top up the oil in my engine?" with "first, you'll need a few blocks of engine-grade metal, a milling machine, a ..."