# C# - How to make programs without IDE/Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, c, notepad++, monodevelop

I am making C# console applications in Notepad++ and MonoDevelop with only a .cs file instead of a solution. I compile the code from CMD.

I want to add two classes in my simple "Hacked" program that just simply displays a lot of 0's and 1's. EVERY time I try to make an object reference, I get an error in the compiler saying that I need to make a reference for non-static fields. Making methods static works, but I don't think that every method should be static.

So my question is, how do I make object references without an IDE?

EDIT: I have found the solution by making the variable static. And I knew that when a method was static, it could be accessed from any class without a reference. I was just testing a class reference to learn a little more about C#. But I make the class reference variable static and anything that isn't static in the referenced class works fine. Thank you all for helping me out though as your suggestions and explanations did help me.

Comment: How about you edit your question with the code you have written, that might help with figuring out what is causing the error. You don't have to use an IDE to write C#

Comment: Althought I believe that @Cyral's answer is the way to go, your main question can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553143/compiling-executing-a-c-sharp-source-file-in-command-prompt). Basically, to generate an `.exe` you just need to open a command line and run: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<version>\csc.exe file.cs You can also find more command line parameters [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 8):

Nice to see someone starting so simple. Object references are the same no matter if you are working in VisualStudio, or in a simple text editor.

This is actually an error in your *code* and not the fact that you are not using an IDE.

I'm assuming you have not gone into object oriented programming too much, and that these are simple, single class programs to help you get started.

In this case, all other methods, fields, etc, are accessed in some way from your `public static Main(string[] args)` method. Static methods are accessible from all classes, and do not require an object instance. Methods and fields accessed without an instance must be static.

So, in this case, yes, every method **does** need to be static.

Check out this question, [What's a "static method"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124102/whats-a-static-method-in-c)

For example, say you create a class called `Math`, and create a `Pow(int x, int power)` (power) method (This is part of the .NET framework). You would make this function `static` because you want ALL classes to be able to access it without creating an instance of the `Math` class.

```
int square = Math.Pow(2, 2); //Static method, no instance needed
```

Now say, you make a class called `Book`, this class has methods such as `GetPagesLeft()`. In this case, it is specific to each instance of a "book", and should not be `static`, because it applies to each instance.

```
Book book = new Book(); //Create instance
int pagesLeft = book.GetPagesLeft(); //Instance method
```

Don't be afraid of using static methods, they are there for a reason.

Note, I'm not a professional developer, so some of the terminology I used may not be exactly correct, but I hope it gets the point across.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think of the fact that it would be a program without a separate set of classes, if he's calling methods written in the class in main, you are absolutely correct.

Answer (score -1):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // instanceMethod();  // Error calling instance method without an instance.
                                  // Won't even compile


            Program prg = new Program();
            prg.instanceMethod(); // No Error calling instance method from instance

            staticMethod(); // No Error calling static method without an instance
        }

    void instanceMethod()
    {

    }

    static void staticMethod() 
    {

    }
}
```

}