# I want to compile a C# file using command prompt

Tags: c#, command-prompt

I wrote a simple C# file. When I compile it using command prompt, I get an error

> 'csc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Do I need to set an environment variable?

Comment: [_"The csc.exe executable file usually is located in the Microsoft.NET\Framework\Version folder under the Windows directory."_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx)

Comment: When you have a VS installed then there should be a "Visual Studio Command Prompt" too. It has those settings preconfigured.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling/Executing a C# Source File in Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553143/compiling-executing-a-c-sharp-source-file-in-command-prompt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you install Visual Studio it comes with it a batch file that sets up the environment for you and opens a cmd window. It's called `Developer Command Prompt for VS201x` (where x is the Visual Studio version you have). It is located in the Visual Studio Tools menu, usually at:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio 201x\Visual Studio Tools
```

This is the result:

[image]

EDIT:

If you don't have Visual Studio installed you can still access the C# compiler shipped with the .NET Framework in Windows 8. You will find it in:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

Otherwise you can install it manually. Here is the [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=17851)

What  you need to do after is just adding it to your environment variable `path`

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's meant can't I compile my file without visual studio :( ??