# Project file could not be loaded, data at root level is invalid, no XML in the project

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to run a hello world C# code from command line and this is the batch file. Tried searching for it but most of the questions are about the XML file reader, **I am not reading any XML files**.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild "E:\a\c.cs" /p:Configuration=Debug;DeployOnBuild=True;PackageAsSingleFile=False;outdir=E:\a

and this is c.cs

```
class c {
    public static void Main() {
        System.Console.Clear();
        System.Console.WriteLine("hey");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

and the error

[image]

Comment: Text editor. Sublime. Yeah both bat and c.cs are in same directory. Otherwise the error would be different I guess, it definitely finds the cs file.

Comment: Not sure, but I have been using sublime for all this time writing other command line stuff never had any issues. And when I try to save as it in notepad it shows ANSI which I am assuming is the encoding of the file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

msbuild expects a project file or a solution file as input:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx

What you want to do is run the c# compiler directly:

[Compiling/Executing a C# Source File in Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553143/compiling-executing-a-c-sharp-source-file-in-command-prompt)

Comment: I am new to .NET, so please bear with me. Will I be able to use the .NET stuff if I compile with c# compiler directly? Basically will it make it different from if I would have done it with visual studio and all the bells and whistles.

Comment: Everything should be available to you without having to use a project file.  But once you get beyond a simple test console application, you will want to have the help of a project file to manage your different files (.cs, .resx etc) as well as their dependencies.

Comment: Good lord I been fighting this for over an hour! --Build succeeded.-- Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are running dotnet with the following command while running.

```
dotnet run --project [project_name].dll
```

You can run the following instead of the above command.

```
dotnet [project_name].dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the Visual Studio, going the arquivo  projects and delete  paste  "**.Vs**" and start the Visual Studio

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check the project file(*.cproj). The file must have the correct Syntax.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31633422)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a .cs file as an entry point.

In 2022:

- You can use Developer command prompt for VS 2022(type in start menu)
- Create a solution/project, include the .cs class in it.
- cd to the solution folder
- `>dotnet build`
- This will create an .exe or .dll if there are no compiler errors
- Make sure you are inside the folder with the .csproj file and run the following command.
- You can add arguments if there's any (dotnet run -- 6)
- `>dotnet run`