# Build an executable file without Microsoft Visual Studio from project file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmd

I don't have MS Visual Studio installed and can't install it due to financial/legal reasons.  I've inherited an executable file built with Visual Studio using C#.  It isn't working as planned.  I can fix the problem by changing 1 line of code.  I have done so, but now I don't know how to re-build the project into an executable without Visual Studio.

I've tried running the following code from the command prompt:

```
>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /t:exe 
/out:exchange.exe exchange.csproj
```

Am I on the right track?

Edit:  This question is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553143) because here I ask about building and compiling a whole project... not just a .cs file.

Comment: You should look to see if you qualify to use the Visual Studio Community edition ([Free under certain conditions](https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/mt171547), and if you *don't* qualify then someone should be able to pay for it or deal with whatever legal problems...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling/Executing a C# Source File in Command Prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553143/compiling-executing-a-c-sharp-source-file-in-command-prompt)

Comment: Crash - I work for a large corporation and our legal department believes that use of the free version could violate Microsoft's usage agreement, so I've been instructed not to install any Visual Studio software since I will not be a regular user.
Sinatr - I tried the solution from that post, but it did not work for me.  The solution from Iris below worked great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest installing [Visual Studio Community edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) (free)

But, if you just want to build using msbuild through the commandline the simplest way would be (assuming you navigated to where msbuild is or have the env path set):

```
msbuild "C:\Users\Something\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Blah path\Hello.csproj"
```

Building (then running) a simple console app that prints hello with the above:

[image]

Comment: This worked perfect!  Thank you for answering my question!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/) for compiling your C# project.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but due to my user privileges I cannot install software like this.  This may work for others though.