# How to run windows form application by cmd

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I created a windows form application from VS 2017. There are 3 files, `Program.cs`, `Form1.Designer.cs`, `Form1.cs`. I want to compile and run it through cmd. I tried to type
     `csc /out:Program.exe Program.cs` but it doesn't work.

The error is :

> cannot find namespace or class 'Form1'.

The application work in VS2017 but not in cmd. Can anyone tell me how to compile and run this application through cmd?

Comment: You can also ``msbuild`` your solution (.sln) from command line if all you are looking for is a way to automatically build your app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling/Executing a C# Source File in Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553143/compiling-executing-a-c-sharp-source-file-in-command-prompt)

Comment: Especially look at the `/r:AssemblyName.dll` part

Comment: You need to provide all the source files to `csc`

Comment: [Creating a Simple C# WinForms Application using a Text Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/winforms/1018/getting-started-with-winforms/11054/creating-a-simple-c-sharp-winforms-application-using-a-text-editor#t=201708210800297494115)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should compile all your classes and not just one on Visual Studio command prompt:

```
csc.exe *.cs /target:winexe /out:Program.exe
```

If you want to create the output exe in `bin` directory of your project's root directory then you can try below command. You need to ensure that `bin` directory is already present before firing the command. This command will *not* create `bin` directory on its own if not present.

```
csc.exe  *.cs /target:winexe /out:.\bin\Program.exe
```

**Note**: `/target` switch helps your launch the output exe as a windows forms application. It you don't mention this switch then it will get launched as console application first which in turns lunches the windows application.

An alternative option is to try `msbuild` command in place of `csc` command on Visual Studio command prompt:

```
msbuild WindowsFormsApplication1.csproj
```

Here you need the project name (*.csproj) in place of individual class files names as command-line parameters. `msbuild` command also takes care of creating any sub directories like `bin`, `debug` if not present.