# Is it possible to compile a single C# code file with the .NET Core Roslyn compiler?

Tags: c#, compilation, .net-core, roslyn, csc

In old .NET we used to be able to run the `csc` compiler to compile a single .cs file or several files.

With .NET Core we have `dotnet build` that insists on having a proper project file. Is there a stand-alone  command line compiler that would allow to compile source code files without having a project (and listing referenced dependencies on the same command line)?

On Linux, when I have the old `csc` and the new .NET Core installed, I get these timings:

```
[root@li1742-80 test]# time dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.409.57025 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  test -> /root/test/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/test.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:03.94

real    0m7.027s
user    0m5.714s
sys     0m0.838s

[root@li1742-80 test]# time csc Program.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.3.0.61801 (3722bb71)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


real    0m0.613s
user    0m0.522s
sys     0m0.071s
[root@li1742-80 test]#
```

Note 7 seconds with .NET Core versus several hundred milliseconds with the old `csc` for the same file, `Program.cs`.

I'd like to be able to compile as fast with .NET Core as I used to be able with `csc`.

Comment: Mildly related: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/building/advanced-inner-loop-testing.md

Comment: I use command line compilation on Windows, Ubuntu and macOS without any problems - see my answer.

Comment: https://github.com/oleg-shilo/cs-script

Comment: @RobertHarvey imo this is not very relevant because CS-Script [requires Mono v5.0.1 or higher](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/cs-script). And asking for mono in order to compile roslyn on Linux is just unreasonable.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible to compile a single file with csc or vbc compilers in .NET Core.**

To invoke the Roslyn compiler directly it is necessary to use the command line driver **csc.{exe|dll}** and since Roslyn in contrast to the old csc.exe does not reference mscorlib.dll implicitly it is necessary to pass a reference to the required dependencies, i.e. `System.Runtime` and `System.Private.CoreLib` libraries and any other required references. The following listing shows how to compile the following *[Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program)* program.

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Using WSL with [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus) and dotnet-sdk-2.0.0 installed:

```
time dotnet /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/Roslyn/csc.exe -r:/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.0.0/System.Private.CoreLib.dll -r:/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.0.0/System.Console.dll -r:/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.0.0/System.Runtime.dll HelloWorld.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.3.2.61921 (ad0efbb6)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

real    0m0.890s
user    0m0.641s
sys     0m0.250s

ls -li
total 4
 4785074604720852 -rw-rw-rw- 1 developer developer  178 Dec  7 15:07 HelloWorld.cs
11821949022487213 -rw-rw-rw- 1 developer developer 4096 Dec  7 15:13 HelloWorld.exe
```

The required dependencies, which are passed to the compiler, are different on different platforms, i.e. on Windows it is enough to pass `System.Runtime.dll` and `System.Console.dll` while on Ubuntu 16.04 it is necessary to pass in addition `System.Private.CoreLib.dll`. Different SDK versions will have Roslyn and command line drivers located in different places - the SDK layout changes between versions - and the newest 2.2.2 SDK ships with `csc.dll` and `vbc.dll` instead of `csc.exe` and `vbc.exe`. Therefore, before using this method it is necessary to check your SDK layout.

**Detailed explanation**

The Roslyn compiler was designed in a bit different way than the previously used `csc.exe` and `vbc.exe` compilers. First of all, Roslyn is written in C# and VB.NET and is a managed .NET application. On Windows it used mainly as a common service running in a server process `VBCSCompiler.exe` (.dll). However, Roslyn ships with managed command line drivers, `csc.exe` and `vbc.exe` (the latest .NET SDK versions ship with `csc.dll` and `vbc.dll`) which can be used to compile source files directly from the command line. Anyway, it is exactly what the build system in .NET does, invoking Roslyn via the command line. Running a simple `dotnet csc.exe -help` command will print usage information which will guide in using the compiler directly from the command line (see the last listing).

The major difference between old native compilers and Roslyn is due to the fact that the latter is a managed application is a startup time. Roslyn, even after being compiled to R2R native assemblies (`Ready To Run`), would need to start by loading the whole .NET framework, initializing it and then loading Roslyn assemblies and starting the compilation process. It is always a bit slower than running the native compiler, however, as can be seen from above timings, not that much slower.

There was a new documentation article added to the `corefx` repository describing [Advanced scenario - Build and run application code with csc/vbc and CoreRun](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/building/advanced-inner-loop-testing.md). Anyone interested can use it as a guideline how to work at the low level of .NET Core.

```
    Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.3.2.61921 (ad0efbb6)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


                              Visual C# Compiler Options

                        - OUTPUT FILES -
 /out:<file>                   Specify output file name (default: base name of
                               file with main class or first file)
 /target:exe                   Build a console executable (default) (Short
                               form: /t:exe)
 /target:winexe                Build a Windows executable (Short form:
                               /t:winexe)
 /target:library               Build a library (Short form: /t:library)
 /target:module                Build a module that can be added to another
                               assembly (Short form: /t:module)
 /target:appcontainerexe       Build an Appcontainer executable (Short form:
                               /t:appcontainerexe)
 /target:winmdobj              Build a Windows Runtime intermediate file that
                               is consumed by WinMDExp (Short form: /t:winmdobj)
 /doc:<file>                   XML Documentation file to generate
 /refout:<file>                Reference assembly output to generate
 /platform:<string>            Limit which platforms this code can run on: x86,
                               Itanium, x64, arm, anycpu32bitpreferred, or
                               anycpu. The default is anycpu.

                        - INPUT FILES -
 /recurse:<wildcard>           Include all files in the current directory and
                               subdirectories according to the wildcard
                               specifications
 /reference:<alias>=<file>     Reference metadata from the specified assembly
                               file using the given alias (Short form: /r)
 /reference:<file list>        Reference metadata from the specified assembly
                               files (Short form: /r)
 /addmodule:<file list>        Link the specified modules into this assembly
 /link:<file list>             Embed metadata from the specified interop
                               assembly files (Short form: /l)
 /analyzer:<file list>         Run the analyzers from this assembly
                               (Short form: /a)
 /additionalfile:<file list>   Additional files that don't directly affect code
                               generation but may be used by analyzers for producing
                               errors or warnings.
 /embed                        Embed all source files in the PDB.
 /embed:<file list>            Embed specific files in the PDB

                        - RESOURCES -
 /win32res:<file>              Specify a Win32 resource file (.res)
 /win32icon:<file>             Use this icon for the output
 /win32manifest:<file>         Specify a Win32 manifest file (.xml)
 /nowin32manifest              Do not include the default Win32 manifest
 /resource:<resinfo>           Embed the specified resource (Short form: /res)
 /linkresource:<resinfo>       Link the specified resource to this assembly
                               (Short form: /linkres) Where the resinfo format
                               is <file>[,<string name>[,public|private]]

                        - CODE GENERATION -
 /debug[+|-]                   Emit debugging information
 /debug:{full|pdbonly|portable|embedded}
                               Specify debugging type ('full' is default,
                               'portable' is a cross-platform format,
                               'embedded' is a cross-platform format embedded into
                               the target .dll or .exe)
 /optimize[+|-]                Enable optimizations (Short form: /o)
 /deterministic                Produce a deterministic assembly
                               (including module version GUID and timestamp)
 /refonly                      Produce a reference assembly in place of the main output
 /instrument:TestCoverage      Produce an assembly instrumented to collect
                               coverage information
 /sourcelink:<file>            Source link info to embed into PDB.

                        - ERRORS AND WARNINGS -
 /warnaserror[+|-]             Report all warnings as errors
 /warnaserror[+|-]:<warn list> Report specific warnings as errors
 /warn:<n>                     Set warning level (0-4) (Short form: /w)
 /nowarn:<warn list>           Disable specific warning messages
 /ruleset:<file>               Specify a ruleset file that disables specific
                               diagnostics.
 /errorlog:<file>              Specify a file to log all compiler and analyzer
                               diagnostics.
 /reportanalyzer               Report additional analyzer information, such as
                               execution time.

                        - LANGUAGE -
 /checked[+|-]                 Generate overflow checks
 /unsafe[+|-]                  Allow 'unsafe' code
 /define:<symbol list>         Define conditional compilation symbol(s) (Short
                               form: /d)
 /langversion:<string>         Specify language version mode: ISO-1, ISO-2, 3,
                               4, 5, 6, 7, 7.1, Default, or Latest

                        - SECURITY -
 /delaysign[+|-]               Delay-sign the assembly using only the public
                               portion of the strong name key
 /publicsign[+|-]              Public-sign the assembly using only the public
                               portion of the strong name key
 /keyfile:<file>               Specify a strong name key file
 /keycontainer:<string>        Specify a strong name key container
 /highentropyva[+|-]           Enable high-entropy ASLR

                        - MISCELLANEOUS -
 @<file>                       Read response file for more options
 /help                         Display this usage message (Short form: /?)
 /nologo                       Suppress compiler copyright message
 /noconfig                     Do not auto include CSC.RSP file
 /parallel[+|-]                Concurrent build.
 /version                      Display the compiler version number and exit.

                        - ADVANCED -
 /baseaddress:<address>        Base address for the library to be built
 /checksumalgorithm:<alg>      Specify algorithm for calculating source file
                               checksum stored in PDB. Supported values are:
                               SHA1 (default) or SHA256.
 /codepage:<n>                 Specify the codepage to use when opening source
                               files
 /utf8output                   Output compiler messages in UTF-8 encoding
 /main:<type>                  Specify the type that contains the entry point
                               (ignore all other possible entry points) (Short
                               form: /m)
 /fullpaths                    Compiler generates fully qualified paths
 /filealign:<n>                Specify the alignment used for output file
                               sections
 /pathmap:<K1>=<V1>,<K2>=<V2>,...
                               Specify a mapping for source path names output by
                               the compiler.
 /pdb:<file>                   Specify debug information file name (default:
                               output file name with .pdb extension)
 /errorendlocation             Output line and column of the end location of
                               each error
 /preferreduilang              Specify the preferred output language name.
 /nostdlib[+|-]                Do not reference standard library (mscorlib.dll)
 /subsystemversion:<string>    Specify subsystem version of this assembly
 /lib:<file list>              Specify additional directories to search in for
                               references
 /errorreport:<string>         Specify how to handle internal compiler errors:
                               prompt, send, queue, or none. The default is
                               queue.
 /appconfig:<file>             Specify an application configuration file
                               containing assembly binding settings
 /moduleassemblyname:<string>  Name of the assembly which this module will be
                               a part of
 /modulename:<string>          Specify the name of the source module
```

Comment: Hi Jack, but what if I do not want to get dll or exe file, but I want something like *.o (C++) or *.class (Java) - compiled file but not packaged in dll or exe, is it possible to do ? I need it for example to package few compiled files in future in my special file format ... Is it possible ?

Comment: Is the `dotnet csc.exe -help` command part of a tool that needs to be installed?

Answer (score 33):

The accepted answer refers to using `System.Private.CoreLib.dll` which is a runtime assembly and is not recommended. From [C# compiler developer's comments](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/16211):

> Attempting to use runtime assemblies as compile references is not
> supported and frequently breaks do to the structure of the runtime
> assemblies

Instead, reference assemblies should be used. Reference assemblies are fetched from NuGet during `dotnet build` and a full `csc` invocation can be seen when running the `dotnet` CLI with increased verbosity (`dotnet build --verbosity normal`). One might see references to assemblies like `System.Runtime.dll` and `System.Console.dll` from `microsoft.netcore.app` NuGet package.

However, for a simple single file *[Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program)* compilation, one can reference `netstandard.dll` which for .NET Core 2.2 exists under `<installation-directory>/sdk/2.2.203/ref/netstandard.dll`.

Note that in order to run the resulting executable with  `dotnet HelloWorld.exe` a corresponding `HelloWorld.runtimeconfig.json` has to be created, containing the targeting .NET Core runtime version. We will simplify it by creating a common runtimeconfig for console (NETCoreApp) apps, and an accompanying alias `csc_run`.

Add the following in your `~/.profile`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# IMPORTANT: make sure dotnet is present in PATH before the next lines

# prepare csc alias

DOTNETDIR=$(dirname $(dirname $(dotnet --info | grep "Base Path" | cut -d' ' -f 6)))
CSCPATH=$(find $DOTNETDIR -name csc.dll -print | sort | tail -n1)
NETSTANDARDPATH=$(find $DOTNETDIR -path *sdk/*/ref/netstandard.dll ! -path *NuGetFallback* -print | sort | tail -n1)

alias csc='dotnet $CSCPATH /r:$NETSTANDARDPATH '

# prepare csc_run alias

if [ ! -w "$DOTNETDIR" ]; then
  mkdir -p $HOME/.dotnet
  DOTNETDIR=$HOME/.dotnet
fi

DOTNETCSCRUNTIMECONFIG=$DOTNETDIR/csc-console-apps.runtimeconfig.json

alias csc_run='dotnet exec --runtimeconfig $DOTNETCSCRUNTIMECONFIG '

if [ ! -f $DOTNETCSCRUNTIMECONFIG ]; then
  DOTNETRUNTIMEVERSION=$(dotnet --list-runtimes |
    grep Microsoft\.NETCore\.App | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f2)

  cat << EOF > $DOTNETCSCRUNTIMECONFIG
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "$DOTNETRUNTIMEVERSION"
    }
  }
}
EOF
fi
```

Exit and start shell to reload profile (or source it `. ~/.profile` if you don't want to leave the current session).

Usage:

```sh
cat << EOF > ./Program.cs
class Program
{
  static void Main() => System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}
EOF

csc     -out:hwapp.exe Program.cs
csc_run hwapp.exe

# Hello World!
```

Comment: This is helpful, although it's not necessarily the case that the SDK will be at version 2.2.203 (or that the framework will be 2.2.4). I think the following works: `DOTNETSDKVER=$(ls $DOTNETDIR/sdk | grep "^[0-9]" | sort -rn | head -1)` although I admit it's rather hacky.

Comment: One can always run `dotnet --info` and look for `Version` under `.NET Core SDK` and for `Microsoft.NETCore.App` version under `.NET Core runtimes installed`

Comment: That's good to know, thanks. I think that parsing the info out of that output in a script is even hackier, so I'll stick with the `ls`-based approach.

Comment: Updated this answer with flexible aliases: `csc` and `csc_run` aliases. It works with console apps. For command line references, see the [compiler options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/index), which can be used with `csc` alias.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler can be directly invoked using

```
$ /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/Roslyn/RunCsc.sh
```

However, this particular command may not be very helpful without a supporting project infrastructure because you'd need to pass in all .NET Core or .NET Standard reference assemblies in manually, which is normally handled by the SDK and NuGet. You'll get errors like this:

```
$ /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/Roslyn/RunCsc.sh Program.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.3.2.61921 (ad0efbb6)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Program.cs(1,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Program.cs(5,11): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
Program.cs(7,26): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
Program.cs(7,16): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
```

Comment: That's a shame, I wish there was a simpler way of compiling a single file.

Comment: There is no way to tell the compiler where to find the referenced assemblies rather than to *tell* it, how else this can be simplified?

Comment: @VMAtm he probably meant that we did not have this problem with good old csc.

Comment: Hints on resolving the errors you mention: https://daveaglick.com/posts/running-a-design-time-build-with-msbuild-apis

Comment: NB The script no longer exists in 2.2.301.

Comment: While trying to write a bit of code to answer a stackoverflow question in C#, I noticed that there is no such script nor any csc.exe in my `ls ~/.dotnet/sdk/3.1.401/Roslyn` directory tree. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an updated script based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56133028/):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
: "${DOTNET_ROOT:=$(dirname "$(dirname "$(dotnet --info | grep "Base Path" | awk '{ print $NF }')")")}"
csc_path=$(find "$DOTNET_ROOT" -name csc.dll -print | sort -V | tail -n1)
ref_path=$(find "$DOTNET_ROOT" -path "*packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/*/ref" -print | sort -V | tail -n1)
read -r -a refs <<<"$(find "$ref_path" -path '*.dll' -printf "-r:%p ")"

# Compile C# source file into '.exe' file.
csc() {
  dotnet "$csc_path" -nologo "${refs[@]}" "$@"
}

# Replace this with your desired path for runtime config.
dotnet_csc_runtimeconfig="$HOME/.cache/csc.runtimeconfig.json"

dotnet_runtime_version=$(dotnet --list-runtimes | grep "Microsoft\.NETCore\.App" | sort -V | tail -n1 | awk '{ print $2 }')
cat <<EOF >"$dotnet_csc_runtimeconfig"
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "$dotnet_runtime_version"
    }
  }
}
EOF

# Run compiled C# '.exe'.
csc-run() {
  dotnet exec --runtimeconfig "$dotnet_csc_runtimeconfig" "$@"
}

echo "Help:"
echo "Use 'csc <SOURCE>.cs' to compile a C# file into '.exe' file."
echo "Use 'csc-run <OUTPUT>.exe' to run a compiled C# '.exe'."
```

Save it as a script, e.g. `setup-csc.sh`, and run:

```bash
# Load the Bash function
. ./setup-csc.sh

# Compile C# file
csc MyProgram.cs

# Run compiled C# file
csc-run MyProgram.exe
```

This script will build an app with all the ".dll"s of current .NET version, and supports all of .NET new features. (Tested on .NET 8.0)

Comment: I was considering supporting NativeAOT in this script, but it seems no easier than generate a `.csproj` file beside the source code and run `dotnet publish -c Release`.

Answer (score 1):

```
This is the scripts:



#!/bin/bash

#dotnethome=`dirname "$0"`
dotnethome=`dirname \`which dotnet\``
sdkver=$(dotnet --version)
fwkver=$(dotnet --list-runtimes | grep Microsoft.NETCore.App | awk '{printf("%s", $2)}')
dotnetlib=$dotnethome/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/$fwkver

if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
    dotnet $dotnethome/sdk/$sdkver/Roslyn/bincore/csc.dll -help
    echo dotnethome=$dotnethome
    echo sdkver=$sdkver
    echo fwkver=$fwkver
    echo dotnetlib=$dotnetlib
    exit 1
fi

progfile=$1
prog="${progfile%.*}"
echo -r:$dotnetlib/netstandard.dll > /tmp/$prog.rsp
echo -r:$dotnetlib/System.dll >> /tmp/$prog.rsp
echo -r:$dotnetlib/Microsoft.CSharp.dll >> /tmp/$prog.rsp
for f in  $dotnetlib/System.*.dll; do
    echo -r:$f >> /tmp/$prog.rsp
done

dotnet $dotnethome/sdk/$sdkver/Roslyn/bincore/csc.dll -out:$prog.dll -nologo @/tmp/$prog.rsp $* 
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
   if test -f "$prog.dll"; then
    if ! test -f "$prog.runtime.config"; then
        echo "{
  \"runtimeOptions\": {
    \"framework\": {
      \"name\": \"Microsoft.NETCore.App\",
      \"version\": \"$fwkver\"
    }
  }
}"  > "$prog.runtimeconfig.json"
    fi
  fi
fi
echo /tmp/$prog.rsp: 
cat /tmp/$prog.rsp
rm /tmp/$prog.rsp
```

Comment: pls reference:https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12393#issuecomment-744142906

Comment: pls references:https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/8742#issuecomment-735047107

Comment: sdk location may differ. consider using this: ```` dotnethome=`dotnet --list-sdks | awk 'match($0,/\/.*\/[^ ]*/){sub("/sdk]","");print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'`
````

Comment: and checking for `$prog.runtime.config` but then writing to `$prog.runtimeconfig.json` :) by the way I liked your post and one of the others to run the result. I am trying to merge them to a single script (works but not single as of now) but can't say if I can finish it (not a guru). You may beat me and have one earlier. Cheers ;)

Answer (score 0):

In short, it's not supported without a predefined project.

But @Andrew's comment shows that it's still possible if you are ready to list every single dependency including implicit system ones in command line options.

From [error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported #12393](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12393#issuecomment-233468174):

> At the moment, we have no plan to make it easy to use csc.exe in this
>   manner. The guidance is to use the dotnet CLI tooling for the time
>   being. Even if some modification where to be made here, it would be on
>   the framework to provide unified and/or simplified reference
>   assemblies for the compiler. The compiler will never have more
>   complicated type or assembly resolution than it does now (by design).

See also the closed *[Make it possible to invoke the compiler directly #7689](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7689)*.

Comment: 20 times slower compile time is surely disappointing. But hey, is their choice ;) Thank you for the answer,

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh, I had to resort to using instead a Win-only Roslyn compiler bundled in MSBuild for compiling single source files without preconfigured project: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553143/compiling-executing-a-c-sharp-source-file-in-command-prompt/47624680#47624680

Comment: Btw, for my purposes RunCsc.sh worked reasonably well. See [here](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tryitonline/blob/master/wrappers/cs-core) and [here](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tiosetup/blob/master/files/dotnet/csopts.txt)