# I can use csc.exe to compile one cs file to a dll in .net framework...but how can i do this in dotnet core by dotnet cli?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In .net framework i can use csc.exe to compile one cs file to a dll file.

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\csc.exe /t:library /out:MyCScode.dll *.cs /debug /r:System.dll /r:System.Web.dll /r:System.Data.dll /r:System.Xml.dll
```

How can i do this in dotnetcore ?

Comment: Say goodbye to the old approach and learn MSBuild and dotnet CLI.

Comment: You can add few lines in your `~/.profile` to setup an alias  on Unix-like OS and compile single file with `csc.dll`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56133028/863980 for details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to compile a single C# code file with the .NET Core Roslyn compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065777/is-it-possible-to-compile-a-single-c-sharp-code-file-with-the-net-core-roslyn-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a minimum you'll need a `.csproj` file with this content:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

That is assuming you'll be targeting [netstandard2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) which would allow your library to run on .NET Framework 4.6.1, .NET Core 2.0 and any other runtime that implements the standard. 
And also have downloaded the [.NET Core 2.0 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core).

Unlike the old `csproj`, there's no need to add the individual `.cs` files to compile them.

So on a directory with such content:

- Class1.cs
- Class2.cs
- Project.csproj (with the content mentioned above)

Simply running: `dotnet build` will output a `dll` at the bin folder as you'd expect.

It's worth mentioning that the .NET Core CLI have templates for ASP.NET Core, class library, xUnit test project, etc:

```
$ dotnet new classlib
```

Would give you the `csproj` and a first class file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [`dotnet build`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build?tabs=netcore2x) to build your project for `asp.net core`