# Can I generate .NET Core assembly with a Roslyn running under .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, roslyn

I would like to compile a .NET Core executable by invoking Roslyn APIs. My "compiler" application is built for .NET Framework, and references Roslyn NuGet packages. So far the assemblies generated by Roslyn as a result were targeted for .NET Framework. And I didn't find a switch to change that. Is that possible, or do I need to use .NET Core version of Roslyn to generate .NET Core executables?

Comment: Use the correct reference assemblies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065777/is-it-possible-to-compile-a-single-c-sharp-code-file-with-the-net-core-roslyn-c

Comment: @HansPassant: that should be submitted as an answer to upvote!