# compiling c# code via the cli on linux with the official .NET SDK

Tags: c#, .net, linux, ubuntu

With mono you'd compile and run C# code by doing `csc test.cs && mono test.exe`. How would you do it with the [official .NET SDK on Ubuntu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-debian)?

Comment: [`dotnet build`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build)

Comment: Have you looked through the docs you linked to? There's a "Hello World" example that spells it out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/get-started and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli

Comment: @GuruStron - when I try `dotnet build test.cs` I get `/home/neubert/test.cs(1,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.`. I guess compiling individual *.cs files isn't possible with dotnet per https://stackoverflow.com/a/47697996/569976...

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47697996/2501279) can help?

Comment: @GuruStron - yah - that was in the link I posted. But the proposed remediation is ~300 bytes long whereas `csc test.cs` isn't anywhere close. I can memorize `csc filename.ext` - I'm not going to memorize that other one. I suppose I could alias it but idk that feels like too much effort lol

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what your goal is:

- `dotnet run` - This will build and run your application directly
- `dotnet test` - This will build everything and run your unit tests
- `dotnet publish` - This will build your application for deployment
- `dotnet build` - This will build your application (for development only). Generally, you don' want to use this: one of the others on this list will be a better way to do what you want. If you want to share this with users, you want `dotnet publish` instead.

Comment: When I try `dotnet build test.cs` I get `/home/neubert/test.cs(1,1): error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.`. I guess compiling individual *.cs files isn't possible with dotnet per https://stackoverflow.com/a/47697996/569976. Oh well...

Comment: The recent versions of .NET don't support compiling/running single files. They expect you to be using a project. There's currently an [active proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/pull/213/files) for enabling single file programs that you can execute directly - similar to running a shell script - but that's just in the design phase right now.