# Compiling a single CS file using the latest framework version

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, build, csc

I would like to compile `myProgram.cs` into `myProgram.exe`.

I know the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\<version number>\csc.exe` file exists that is just doing that, but it is not using the latest framework version. AFAIK, starting from .NET 5.0, C# uses `dotnet.exe build` to compile.

However, this command requires a C# project `*.csproj` as an input, while I want to compile only a single file.

I have found this related [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065777/is-it-possible-to-compile-a-single-c-sharp-code-file-with-the-net-core-roslyn-c), but it seems to have only answers concerning Linux. I do not have a `csc.exe` file under `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.203\Roslyn\bincore` or elsewhere in the SDK.

Where could the `csc.exe` be located? Or what command would be its equivalent for C# running on .NET 5.0+?

---

I tried to find all my `csc.exe` using [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/), but I can't seem to find a relevant one. It's worth nothing that I do have a few `csc.exe` files under specific software paths like:

- C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.30f1\Editor\Data\MonoBleedingEdge\lib\mono\4.5\csc.exe
- C:\Program Files\JetBrains\JetBrains Rider 2021.3.3\tools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe
- C:\Users\\Perforce\\Engine\Binaries\ThirdParty\Mono\Linux\lib\mono\4.5\csc.exe

Perhaps I could use these `csc.exe` instances as a workaround, but it does not solve the issue.

I also tried to use `dotnet build`, but I cant find a way to compile a single CS file with it.

I have found this related [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065777/is-it-possible-to-compile-a-single-c-sharp-code-file-with-the-net-core-roslyn-c), but it doesn't solve my issue, since I am

1. Using Windows instead of Linux
2. Not seeing any `scs.exe` file a the specified path

Comment: I think this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55775370/