Is it possible to compile a single C# code file with .NET 8 or C# 12
We can build and run a single file C# code with mono compiler up to C# 6. But for latest C# version - C# 12 - Mono doesn't have support for it. So, is there a way we can run a single file C# code with .NET 8?
I know we can build a simple console project, but I want to know if we can do it without creating a project or .csproj file.

Are you talking "single file" in terms of a self-contained executable as the result, or a single source file? If you could give more details about what you're trying to do, that would help.

The following may be of interest: Single-file deployment

If you've tagged this "dotnet-cli", what does the mono compiler have to do with this? Are you talking about CS-Script? What about any of the options on this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065777/is-it-possible-to-compile-a-single-c-sharp-code-file-with-the-net-core-roslyn-c ? But I'm not sure what advantage you're expecting to see by not making a project file and compiling the file yourself.
