# How to configure dependencies correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, powershell

What I would basically like to know is if there is a way of knowing which versions of all the NuGet packages my project depends on/requires, so that I can configure each one accordingly. A PowerShell command that would provide the above would be great.

I receive the below error when I build my solution:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The "Csc" task failed unexpectedly. System.TypeLoadException:
>   Could not load type 'System.ValueTuple`3' from assembly 'mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>   at
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.ManagedToolTask.GenerateCommandLineCommands()
>   at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() NBC.CMS.Cms

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, you can quickly see the Dependencies and what version they are expected by the following:

.NET-Framework Solutions

1. Your App.config file will show you all NuGet downloaded dependencies
2. Follow Solution->Project->References for all NuGet and System dependencies

.NET-Core

1. Solution->Dependencies->NuGet

If you are looking for a CLI solution, try the following solutions.

Visual Studio

1. Click Tools->NuGet Package Manager->Package Manager Console
2. Once the terminal opens, type in "Get-Package"

PowerShell (outside of Visual Studio)

1. dotnet list package YourSln.sln

Some answers referenced here:

[Get a list of all NuGet packages used in a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53435715/get-a-list-of-all-nuget-packages-used-in-a-solution)

[How to list all installed NuGet Packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363960/how-to-list-all-installed-nuget-packages)

Answer (score -1):

```
Get-Module -listavailable
```

Then find the version