# How to create exe file to Program.cs file while running another program in C#

Tags: c#

I am a student and I am during my final project.

In my project I give an option to edit code and run it. The problem is, that I do not know how to create a new exe file after changing the code.

I would be happy if you can help me !!!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling/Executing a C# Source File in Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553143/compiling-executing-a-c-sharp-source-file-in-command-prompt)

Comment: This should allow you to compile the code using CMD : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553143/compiling-executing-a-c-sharp-source-file-in-command-prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile code into assemblies and then execute them as such.

This example should cover what I mean:

https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/System.CodeDom.Compiler/CodeDomProvider/CompileAssemblyFromFile/php-codedomprovider-compileassemblyfromfile-method-examples.html

You can access the compiled assembly from CompiledResults and run it directly in the current AppDomain like a script of some sorts or you can store it to an .exe

Comment: i don't know why someone downvoted this.  this is amazing info.

Comment: @JohnLord I think so too :)

Comment: I used the code that you gave me in the example and there is a very big problem... it doesn't recognize the namespace he is in... do you have any idea how can i solve it? Thank you anyway!!!!

Comment: @AyalaFinch You can specify the namespace when calling it, I assume you have issue with the MainClass.

Just do 'MyNamespace.MyClass'.