# How to compile & execute text in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compilation, operating-system, cosmos

I am working on an operating system with Cosmos, I am wondering if there is a way to compile text from a file, for example: helloworld.cs, and then execute the file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553143/compiling-executing-a-c-sharp-source-file-in-command-prompt).

Comment: @bdongus I'm not sure Pikalover is asking within the context of how to turn helloworld.cs into helloworld.exe on a *Windows* system...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compile a c# file (.cs) like `helloworld.cs` in Windows

```
namespace test {
    class test {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }

}
```

you can use `csc.exe` to compile the file

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\{version}\csc.exe pathToFile`

Comment: Does it exist on Cosmos OS? Just like that.. in C:\windows and all.. (seeing as Cosmos != windows)

Comment: As far as I understand the OP is building an operating system with the Cosmos framework. He made no statement about his dev environment.

Comment: I think I stated it wrong, I want to run code from a file in c#.  For example inside hello.cs, there is a command to run World.cs.

Comment: maybe this can help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider