# C# CodeDom how to compile a windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, compilation, resources, codedom

I'm creating an winform app that compiles another winform app programmatically using CodeDom
but there are not plenty of examples and explanations In the web i need a way to compile a
whole windows form with its resource.resx file and designer.cs file because i only found examples that compile console applications

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553143/compiling-executing-a-c-sharp-source-file-in-command-prompt

Comment: Also, you could always merge partial files into one larger file (like the designer files with the actual class files), to then compile the designer files.

Comment: I take it you want to use CodeDom only to compile, not to generate the code? CodeDom will only generate c# code, not a resource.resx file.